# Training an assistant in Portuguese, Rasa NLU not running with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rasa-nlu

I am working with Rasa NLU. I want to train a language model in Portuguese and have it running inside a Container. I can train the language dataset but I am not being able to get it to run.

I've created an Image from the official rasa_nlu, running with the spacy Portuguese pipeline, and placed in a Container on Docker.

I am able to use the `rasa_nlu.train`command to train the language model without problems, or at least that what it seems.
When I try to run it using the data that I trained, I get an error message complaining about missing parameters on the command that I used.

Here is the docker-compose service that I try to use when running the container:

```
rasa_nlu:
    image: rasa_nlu_pt
    volumes:
      - ./models/rasa_nlu:/app/models
    command:
      - start
      - --path
      - /app/models
```

and it gives the following error message:

```
usage: run.py [-h] -d CORE [-u NLU] [-v] [-vv] [--quiet] [-p PORT]
              [--auth_token AUTH_TOKEN] [--cors [CORS [CORS ...]]]
              [--enable_api] [-o LOG_FILE] [--credentials CREDENTIALS]
              [-c CONNECTOR] [--endpoints ENDPOINTS] [--jwt_secret JWT_SECRET]
              [--jwt_method JWT_METHOD]
run.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--core
```

The same happens if I run it without other containers:

```
$ docker run   -v $(pwd):/app/project   -v $(pwd)/models/rasa_nlu:/app/models -
p 5000:5000 rasa_nlu_pt start --path app/models
usage: run.py [-h] -d CORE [-u NLU] [-v] [-vv] [--quiet] [-p PORT]
              [--auth_token AUTH_TOKEN] [--cors [CORS [CORS ...]]]
              [--enable_api] [-o LOG_FILE] [--credentials CREDENTIALS]
              [-c CONNECTOR] [--endpoints ENDPOINTS] [--jwt_secret JWT_SECRET]
              [--jwt_method JWT_METHOD]
run.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--core
```

I used the same command to run the service with the English spacy pipeline provided by Rasa and it worked as it should, but now it is giving this error message. That other information I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which pipeline your are using for your NLU, you should use the rasa/nlu:tensorflow-latest oder rasa/nlu:spacy-latest and not the rasa/nlu:latest. This will solve the problem.